# ATACseq pipeline report generation issue

Tags: atac-seq

I am trying to run `ATACseq` pipeline:

https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/esATAC.html

On single end `ATACseq` experiments.

```
conclusion_micro12 <- atacPipe("mm10", fastqInput1 = paste0(base_folder, "Micro_atac12.fastq.gz"),
                   adapter1 = "CAAGCAGAAGACGGCATACGAGATAGCGTAGCGTCTCGTGGGCTCGGAGATGT",
                   threads = 4,
                   createReport = TRUE)
```

It generated several folders during its run: `esATAC_report`, `esATAC_result`, `intermediate_results`, `refdir`. However, only the last two gets populated, the others being empty. I am not sure what is going on. I looked over various log files in the `intermediate_results` folder, but it does not say much. Where should I look to figure out what went wrong? I would expect a report to be generated if everything is fine since I specified `createReport = TRUE`. While running the pipeline it does not show any errors in `Rstudio` console.